# Django - background processing without using any external message-broker and related packages

Tags: python, django, multithreading, concurrency, multiprocessing

I have to solve this issue: i have a 4G/4Core Ubuntu server 18.04LTS based machine with my django application, postgres, redis, and some other services that runs off my web application.

The nature of the application is quite simple: every 5 minutes i have to collect data and save it to my db from remote devices via SNMP protocol, the total number of devices is around 300.

I want to start this task without slowing down my application, so i've offloaded this task, i've tried both Threads, Multiprocessing and Django-RQ/python-rq.

Now, here are the results:

- `Threads`: 1800 seconds
- `Multiprocessing`: 180 seconds (using `fork` method as default context, but i'm having random deadlocks, so is totally unusable after all)
- `Python-RQ and Django-RQ` with 12 workers: 180/200 seconds

Now, it seems that my operations are all `I/O bound`, so, excluding the multiprocessing approach, the background worker with Python-rq seems effective, but i'm experiencing that it eats up all my memory.

You guys, have a solution? i mean: the multiprocessing way using fork as default context is totally unusable due to the random deadlock..but the python-rq/django-rq solution is functional and heavy!

How i can use the multiprocessing module with `spawn` as default context, load Django and then feed the created process with the tasks to execute?

You have some alternatives?